# Detect Visible Width of Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a general programming question (it doesn't have a specific purpose/application yet).

If I create a tag in HTML (lets say an img, a, or div), but don't define its width or use a percent width (ie `width:50%`) how would I go about finding the actual width it is displaying (in pixels) using javascript? I would also perfer for it to be crossbrowser, but that isn't my major concern.

I mean I know that if it is a block element like div it will take `100%`, but how do I find what `100%` is? Do I just have to climb the node tree until I find a parent node with a defined width and then calculate it based on that?

I am aware of `clientWidth` and `clientHeight`, but neither of those are crossbrowser or w3 approved...

Comment: If you use percentages it's going to return percentages when you query it. It sounds like you're trying to get a static value (i.e. 450px) out of a percentage value (i.e. 50%). You can't really do that unless you run some math (find the static value of the width of the container and do the math with the percentage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) function in jQuery's API. This is definitely cross-browser and returns the width in pixels (see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/) for details).

Comment: Thanks definitely what I need, but if I don't want to use jQuery, is there an alternative?

Comment: @Tomas What is acceptable to you: raw JavaScript (no framework) or some other framework (like MooTools)? Yes, I think you can just rewrite this function to avoid implementing whole framework.

Comment: Well, as I said this isn't going to be applied to anything just yet. But I'm seeing if I can do it in raw JS to avoid importing a whole framework for just .width()

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution would be to use a prototype method

```
Element.prototype.getElementWidth = function() {
    if (typeof this.clip !== "undefined") {
          return this.clip.width;
    } else {
      if (this.style.pixelWidth) {
          return this.style.pixelWidth;
      } else {
             return this.offsetWidth;
      }
    }
};
```

Comment: Do not overwrite default prototypes. It's bad practice.